# Show live preview of HTML template in a vue application

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, iframe

I have a POST endpoint that returns HTML code. It's a dynamically generated landing page, and its UI is based on the parameters provided in that POST request. For example:

```
axios.post('/api/preview', {headerColor: 'green', footerColor: 'blue'}); // returns the HTML page with styles built based on the request body params
```

I want to have a live preview of that HTML page, in a 400px window. It would be great if the page adjusts to that 400px width, and have scrollable height.

I was thinking of 2 ways to do it:

1. Iframe, but I can't pass the content of a POST request to the iframe.
2. `v-html`, but then I can't force the content to adjust to my 400px container width, and it adds the `HEAD` and `script` elements to the website DOM without any iframe, so it can pollute the global things.

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store those properties coming from the API in data() properties and then bind the styles/classes dinamically using v-bind.

Could you please post more code of the landing page that is consuming the API data?